# EHCI USB Controller and USB Device (gadget) mode

Tags: usb, linux-device-driver

In SoC I'm working on there is USB EHCI Compatible Controller. 
Does all EHCI Controllers can work as Host or Device ?
Does EHCI Linux driver cover device/gadget mode for such controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EHCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EHCI#EHCI) is a Host controller only, there is no specified way for one to function as a device, and it does not support [USB OTG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go). Your SoC's controller most likely provides an EHCI compatible interface for the Host controller, using a different interface for the Device controller.